# ios Approach to implement app from iPad only to Universal

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

I currently develop an app just on iPad only and it exists on Apple store. Now I want to make it on iPhone. I figure out myself two ways to do this:

1. Add a folder iphone on my existing project for iPad. I will put all code and resources just for iPhone on this folder. On my opinion, this will make my app heavier because user download my app from iPhone will have iPad resources but useless, it wastes.
2. Create absolutely new project for iPhone which has the same name with existing iPad app. I think Apple will consider it a branch new app because of different bundleID. I doubt with this approach.

So how can I do it for the best, most convenient and usual like everybody does?

Comment: If there are no big changes in what your app does, the logic flow and the functionality, you could do the switch by just implementing a new UI (Storyboard/XIB/code) for your app, which fits all the elements onto the iPhone screen. You don't really need to create a new project or a new folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

approach 1 will make the app larger cos it contains 2 sorts of code and ui element images, but its easy for users to install and use your app.
second approach is allowed by apple, and much easier to maintain the code cos you have 2 logics to match 2 kinds of devices

Comment: The approach may also depend on whether your app is free or paid - If it is free then you can have two apps without much impact - if it is paid, then with approach 2 a user who has bought your app on iPad will need to purchase the iPhone version separately.  With approach 1 they can access the app on their phone for no cost

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11, you really figure out the point, I forgot, my app is paid one so I think approach 1 is better